# Component inside another component not working - webpack - Vue.js 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-loader

I am totally new to Vue.js and hence I feel the issue is very simple. Here is my `Test.vue` component:

```
<template>
  <p>Hello Worldd</p>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name : 'test'
}
</script>
```

I am trying to display this "Hello Worldd" in another component called `UserDevices.vue`. Here is the contents of that file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <test></test>
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Test from './Test'

export default {
  name: 'UserDevices',
  components: {Test}
}
```

I am getting an error says:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <test> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <UserDevices> at src/components/UserDevices.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

I am using webpack scaffold for vue as template. Isn't this the correct approach to do this?

Comment: I think the problem could be that the `components` object will be expanded to `{ 'Test': Test }` and you don't have a component called 'Test` -- it's called 'test'.  Try defining `components` as `{ 'test' : Test }`.

Comment: Alright. I have changed the tag name to `test-tag` and importing as `import Test from './Test'`. Initialised it as `components: {'test-tag':Test}`. Still no luck.

Comment: You don't close the script tag `</script>` in the code you've shared. Is that a copy/paste error? If not, that's probably the issue.

Comment: @thanksd Oh my god.! Thanks alot. That was exactly the issue. You are a life saver. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a `.vue` file, meaning that [vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/) is looking for a script section enclosed in `<script>` tags. But, because you are not closing the script tag with `</script>`, vue-loader will just ignore that section of the `.vue` file (without any warning).

The template of the Vue component will still get loaded, but the Vue instance's model (with all of its data properties, methods, component, etc.) will not. This is why Vue can't find the `<test>` component.